# Movie title after ':' (colon)

Tags: lists, titles, colons

When I'm writing a sentence like this:

Favorite movie: Batman

Do I put *Batman* in italics or not?

Comment: I don't think what you've written qualifies as a *sentence* under most definitions, but whether or not something is italicized or not is essentially unrelated to any punctuation that surrounds it. The colon here is simply a separator between a label and a value.

Answer (score 1):

Colons and italics live independent lives.  Thus the choice to italicize Batman or not after a colon has nothing to do with the colon.   There is no grammar rule here.

There may be style reasons to do this.  If your document has decided to italicise all movie titles then the important thing is to be consistent.  Again, that has nothing to do with the colon.

> **colon**
>
> a punctuation mark (:) indicating.
>
> - that a writer is introducing a quotation or a list of items.
> - that a writer is separating two clauses of which the second expands or illustrates the first.
>
> [google: colon](https://www.google.com/search?q=italics&oq=italics&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=colon)
>
> **Italics**
>
> Italics are a way to emphasise key points in a printed text, or when quoting a speaker a way to show which words they stressed. One manual of English usage described italics as "the print equivalent of underlining".
>
> [google: italics](https://www.google.com/search?q=italics&oq=italics&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

In your last sentence you made fine use of italics to stress Batman to show you were talking about the word and not the Batman.

You may use the colon and context in place of italics.  In your second sentence it's abundantly clear that you are not referring to the character but a movie title.  Adding italics as well at that point adds very little.

There are times when italics for movie titles are called for.  Not so much in a list of movie titles.